# Page Object Pattern for Xcode 7 UI Tests

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, pageobjects

Has anyone successfully implemented the Page Object pattern in their UI tests?  I gave it a try and ran into an issue.  When I use the predicate to wait for the element to exist, I get a warning in the log.  Here's a code snippet from the Page Object class:

```
XCUIElement *myCoolButton = self.app.buttons[@"Super Cool Button"];
[self expectationForPredicate:self.existsPredicate evaluatedWithObject:myCoolButton handler:nil];
[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5.0f handler:nil];
```

When this code executes, I see the following in the log:

```
Questionable API usage: creating XCTestExpectation for test case -[MyPageObject (null)] which is not the currently running test case -[MyTestCase test]
```

and when the timeout is exceeded, I see the error in the log but the test itself doesn't actually fail.  I'm assuming that this is because the predicate is set up in the Page Object class, not the test itself.  Has anyone been able to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, I assume waitForExpection is written in the Page Objects class.

Generally Page Objects are not inherited from XCTestCase since they are used only to hold references of all the UI Elements possibly in a page.Hence they cannot have assert actions(waitForExpectation in this case)

If what you are trying is to write a re-usable function which can have assertions  like waitForExpectation in the PageObject class then you need to pass the test case as a parameter to the function(Your function should accept a test case)

For this case ,I would suggest you to write a category(extension in swift) on XCTestCase with XCUIElement as an input param which waitsForTheElementToExist instead of writing in the pageobject class.You can avoid replicating the same code in all page objects.

Sample code here

```
class LoginPageObect {
 let userNameTextField  = XCUIApplication().textFields["UserName"]
 let passwordTextField = XCUIApplication().textFields["Password"]

  func loginUser(testcase: XCTestCase) {
    testcase.waitForElementToAppear(userNameTextField)
    testcase.waitForElementToAppear(passwordTextField)
     //Do rest of things here
   }
 }
extension XCTestCase {
  func waitForElementToAppear(element: XCUIElement) {
    let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    expectationForPredicate(existsPredicate,
                            evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shahid. You are correct, I inherited my Page Object class from XCTestCase.  I'll give the extension a shot.  However, would we run into the same issue of the timeout not failing the test since I will be using the XCUIElement extension in the page object class (not the test itself)?

Comment: @ryasui: Sorry ryasui, meant write an extension on the XCTestCase which accepts a XCUIElement..edited the answer accordingly

Comment: @ryasui: Page Objects should not be doing any assertions. So you wouldn't  need to write waitForExpection in the page objects class. Ideally it should only have references to the objects of the view which are used in the testcase class to write corresponding tests and assertions

Comment: Hi Shahid.  Sorry, I'm not sure I follow.  I agree that Page Objects should not be doing the assertions.  However, when I've used this pattern in the past, I've encapsulated all interactions with the UI in the page object, including the waits for the UI elements to exist, so that the tests themselves wouldn't have to worry about such things.  Granted this comes from writing tests for a Web UI with WebDriver/Java so I'm not sure how that applies to iOS tests.

Comment: In any case, back to your answer.  The part that I'm not following is the extension of XCTestCase.  How would that help since the waits are in the page object?  Or is the test framework not set up to handle this pattern so all wait predicates have to be in the test class itself?

Comment: waitForExpectationsWithTimeout is defined on XCTestCase so would not be able to use with page objects unless you subclass it. If you are not planning to subclass(which I believe we shouldn't ) then I have attached  sample code in the answer. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I did the first part where you pass the testcase to the page object and that solved my issue.  I'll add the extension so I don't have the waitForExpectationsWithTimeout everywhere.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the same idea of passing the testCase by parameter, but it became pretty ugly later. One of the approaches (the one I prefere) for PageObjects says you should not have asserts on Pages.

So I came up with this implementation:

```
class Page {
    required init(_ c: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        c?(waitForExistence())
    }
    func waitForExistence() -> Bool {
        fatalError("Subclass of Page should override \(#function)")
    }
}
```

Then, instead of using the `waitForExpectation`, which would require XCTestCase, you can use the new XCode9 API for *XCUIElement*: `waitForExistence(timeout:)` (or `XCTWaiter` if you need a more complex *expectation*)

```
class LoginPage: Page {
    override func waitForExistence() -> Bool {
        return XCUIApplication().otherElements["view_login"].waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
    }
```

And the use would be:

```
LoginPage { 
   XCTAssertTrue($0, "Login page not shown") 
}
.type(email: "solid@snake.com")
```